# Cannot able to pass data from Node to asp.net MVC

Tags: node.js, asp.net-mvc, axios

On the button click event of React side I am calling a node backend.

click event of react,

```
// calling node backend
this.uploadApi.command(postData.bin_files, this.dummy);
this.setState({submit_form});
    }
    dummy = (result)=>{
        console.log(result);
    }
```

This is my Node backend code,

```
import axios from 'axios';


class UploadFile {
    constructor() {
        this.url = 'http://localhost:56246/microservice/uploaddata'; //This is the local MVC application's URL (microservice is the controller)
       
    }

    command(postData, callback, uploadCallback = null) {
        let jsonDataString = JSON.stringify(postData).replace(/&/g, '--and--');
        jsonDataString = jsonDataString.replace(/\+/g, '--plus--');
       
        const payload = JSON.parse(jsonDataString);
      
        console.log('----------');
        console.log(this.url);
        console.log(payload);
        console.log('----------');
        // var data = qs.stringify({'jsondata':payload});
        const data = new FormData();
        for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
            console.log('inside for 1');
            data.append(`model[${i}].name`, payload[i].name);
            data.append(`model[${i}].bin_file`, payload[i].bin_file);
            console.log('inside for 2');
        }
        console.log('=============');
        console.log(data);
        console.log('=============');
        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: this.url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            data: "jsondata=" + data,
            onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                const {
                    loaded,
                    total
                } = progressEvent;
                console.log("loaded:", loaded);
                console.log("total:", total);
                if (uploadCallback !== null) uploadCallback(progressEvent);
            }
        };

        axios(config)
            .then(function(response) {
                // console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                callback(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

        // axios.post(this.url, data)
        //     .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        //     .catch((error) => { console.error(error) });


    }
}

export default UploadFile;
```

And this is my respective controller,

```
public dynamic UploadData(List<MemberInfo> model)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = mstrDBConStringNew;
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tempstorage", conn);
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //port = reader.GetString(0);
                    }
                }
            }
            return "Hiiiiiiii";
        }

        public class MemberInfo
        {
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string bin_file { get; set; }
        }
```

Now If I show You while debugging, the controller and its respective action gets called but the value that I am expecting is null.
[image]

I have also tried like this way, but no luck

```
public dynamic UploadData(FormCollection model)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = mstrDBConStringNew;
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tempstorage", conn);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //port = reader.GetString(0);
                }
            }
        }
        return "Hiiiiiiii";
    }
```

This is my network request,

[image]

Please ask if anything additional is needed.

Comment: Can you open the browser's Developer Tools (F12) -> Network tab -> Select the webrequest that's being sent and post the request body?

Comment: @Pieterjan done , take a look

Comment: Sorry for the delay. We need the request body as well. After selecting the request in developer tools, a sidepanel appears and when you select **Response** you get the json. That's what we need

Comment: @Pieterjan Hey man , thanks for Your help, I was using data as data: "jsondata=" + data, but when I remove concatenation it is working and I am getting the result as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I was able to figure out the issue,

```
var config = {
            method: 'post',
            url: this.url,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            data: data, // previously it was, "jsondata=" + data
```

Here I am getting the data as expected..
[image]